# Filtering dictionary items based on another list

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I have a dictionary with tuples as keys (my_dict) and I also have a list of values that I am interested in (my_list).

I want to create a new dictionary where I only keep the tuples and values for the cases where the first element of the tuple is included in my list of values. Is there a fast way to do this?

For example:

```
my_dict = {('1', '2'): 'a', ('1', '3'): 'b', ('2', '3'): 'c', ('3', '4'): 'd', ('4', '5'): 'a', ('4', '6'): 'b', ('5', '6'): 'e', ('6', '7'): 'f'}

my_list = ['1', '2', '6']
```

The output should be:

```
my_new_dict = {('1', '2'): 'a', ('1', '3'): 'b', ('2', '3'): 'c', ('6', '7'): 'f'}
```

Comment: Cool story. What is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic approach: A `dict` comp with a filter:

```
In [807]: {k : v for k, v in my_dict.items() if k[0] in my_list}
Out[807]: {('1', '2'): 'a', ('1', '3'): 'b', ('2', '3'): 'c', ('6', '7'): 'f'}
```

If you're using python2, you'll need `my_dict.iteritems()`.

---

To improve efficiency, convert `my_list` to a `set`:

```
my_set = set(my_list)
res = {k : v for k, v in my_dict.items() if k[0] in my_set}
print(res)
```

Lookup becomes more efficient when filtering.